# transfer data from text table to normal table hsqldb java

Tags: java, sql, file, hsqldb

I am trying to transfer data from a text table to a normal table, where the data is taken originally from a txt file.

I am using hsqldb

This is what I did. I have no error or exception , but both the tables are empty.

```
String sqlkeywordcreate=new String ("CREATE TABLE keywordsTable " + " (k_id INTEGER IDENTITY not NULL PRIMARY KEY,  keywords varchar(20))");
        String sqlkeywordcreate1=new String ("CREATE TEXT TABLE tempKeywordsTable " + " (key varchar(20))");
        stmt1.executeUpdate(sqlkeywordcreate);
        stmt1.executeUpdate(sqlkeywordcreate1);
        int numOfFields=di.getAllTerms();
String setTempKeywordsTable= new String ("set table "+"tempKeywordsTable"+ " source 'keywords.txt'");
        //System.out.print(setTempKeywordsTable);
        stmt1.executeUpdate( setTempKeywordsTable);
        String insertkey=  new String("INSERT INTO keywordsTable "+"(keywords)"+ " select key from tempKeywordsTable");
        stmt1.executeUpdate(insertkey);
        String dropTempKey= new String("drop table tempKeywordsTable");
        //stmt1.executeUpdate(dropTempKey);
        String sqlcreate=new String("CREATE TABLE "+ tableName +" (id INTEGER IDENTITY not NULL PRIMARY KEY)");
        String sqlselect=new String("select k_id from keywordsTable");
```

Please guide me and give me ideas to solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks correct. You should add a test count after the line with "set table tempKeywordsTable source " to make sure the data is linked properly to the TEXT table. If there is data, the rest will work.

A possible cause of your code not working is the path of the keywords.txt file. This file should be in the same directory as the rest of the database files.